# Use AWS EC2 tag to determine S3 access policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have multiple AWS EC2 instances that have unique name tags of the form `***-manager` (three unique characters then `-manager`).

I have several S3 buckets (and sub-folders in them) with similar 3-character id's in their names that I need to restrict access to depending on which EC2 is asking.

How could I write a single AWS policy to attach to every EC2 that would do the following:

1. The bucket `docker.***.mysite.com` should only be accessible by the EC2 whose name tag has value `***-manager`. Action is anything, i.e. `*`.
2. The folder `downloads.mysite.com/***/` should only be accessible by the EC2 whose name tag has value `***-manager`. The action is `ListBucket` and `GetObject` with a prefix restriction.
3. The folder `downloads.mysite.com/common/` should be accessible by any EC2

No EC2 should have access to the root `downloads.mysite.com/` or know anything about it (i.e., can't do any S3 action outside of the `common` and its `***` subfolder.

NOTE: If it's not easy/possible to extract the 3-letter id from the EC2 name tag to "pass" to the Resource part of the policy I can easily add a new tag to each EC2 that just has the `***` as its value - but still have to "pass" that somehow to the Resource in the policy definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it will be possible to create one policy for multiple situations.

The closest method would be to use [IAM Policy Elements: Variables - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html), but that does not allow use of an arbitrary value nor can it be used to retrieve a tag from an EC2 instance.

I think you'll need to create separate Roles for each EC2 instance that refer to the specific S3 buckets.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way how to do this because IAM S3 policies can't look back for the "caller tags".

What can be done though is lookup the tags of the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance. Unfortunately the relevant condition on `GetObject` action is `s3:ExistingObjectTag/<key>`, which works on the S3 object rather than on the S3 bucket itself.

A simplified policy using the above would look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_BUCKET_NAME>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowROcheckTag",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/<TAG_ON_S3_OBJECT>": "aws:RequestTag/<TAG_ON_IAM_ROLE_ASSIGNED_TO_EC2>}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above case it would be the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance and its tags driving the access to the objects in the S3 bucket.

Details about allowed conditions for specific S3 action is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html)